# Invoke-WebRequest with Credential will trigger the login form on a page with ajax

Tags: ajax, powershell, authentication

I am making a Powershell script to get the content from the page. The script is working but with pages where there is Ajax/Javascript on the page my Powershell script triggers a new login window.  This causes the powershell script to hang until the credentials are filled in.

Another thing that maybe is useful is when I press "cancel", I still get the page back.

```
$username = ''
$password = ''
$usr =  $username
$pwd = $password | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force

$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($usr,$pwd)
$page = Invoke-WebRequest "" -DisableKeepAlive $false -Credential $cred -        TimeoutSec 30

$page
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a session variable and then use that session variable as the **-WebSession** in future **invoke-webrequest** calls.

Example:

```
$my_domains_start = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://some_url" -SessionVariable cookie
$my_domains = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ( $page.forms[2].Action ) -WebSession $cookie -Method POST -Body $my_domains_start.forms[2].fields
```

Mind you, there will be customization based on the login fields for the page that you're passing the authentication to since each site is different but in short, you should be able to continue using the websession and pass from page to page without having to authenticate again.